# How prove this inequality $I=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sin{x^2}dx>0$

Tags: analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

show that
$$I=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sin{x^2}dx>0$$

follow is my methods: let
$$x^2=t$$
then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac{\sin{t}}{2\sqrt{t}}dt+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\dfrac{\sin{t}}{2\sqrt{t}}dt=\int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac{\sin{t}}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi+t}}\right)dt$$
since
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi+t}}>0$$
so $$I>0$$

My quuestion: have other methods? Thank you

Comment: IS it $\sqrt{2\pi}$?

Comment: Your method looks fine to me.

Comment: Aren't you happy with what you did?

Answer (score 1):

Lazy answer: the [Fresnel sine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) is positive for any positive argument.

Comment: why Fresnel sine is positive then my inequality is positive?

Comment: Look for the Fresnel sine definition.

Comment: I don't know why? $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{(x^2)}dx=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{4}$$ then how prove $$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sin{(x^2)}dx>0?$$

Comment: I said the Fresnel sine. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

Comment: I know this,Thank you.But I can't use this fresnel sine reslut,prove my inequality?

Comment: Daout? How it? can you post it? Thank you